# How to make a Shortcuts message automation to add number to a contact

Tags: iphone, messages, contacts, automation, shortcuts-app

I'd like to create a shortcuts automation on my phone to automatically add spam messages to a "Spam" contact. However, I can't get the shortcut to work. This is what I currently have

[image]

This is for a "when I get a message containing text" automation.

This pops up the automation whenever I get a message, but when I run it, it does nothing.

Comment: Hmm, actually it looks like "Shortcut Input" was set to "message", but I think it should be set to "sender". I don't know if there's an easy way to test this, so I'll just have to wait to see if it works.

Comment: To test it, you could just run the automation on a message from someone you know, then remove them from the spam contact.